# WebUI Deprecated mail even after the following the steps mentioned in Xamarin forum

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Recently we have been receiving the UIWebView deprecated warnings from Appstore, for which xamarin forms has directed the developers to do the below four things

> Update Xamarin.Forms to 4.5 or higher – Pre-release versions of Xamarin.Forms 4.5 can be used.
>
> Use Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher – Check your Xamarin.iOS version in Visual Studio. This version of Xamarin.iOS is included with Visual Studio for Mac 8.4.1 and Visual Studio 16.4.3.
>
> Remove references to UIWebView – Your code should not have any references to UIWebView or any classes that make use of UIWebView.
>
> And add the additional mtouch argument ‘--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type’

But even after doing all those things we are still getting the warning mail form apple.
We are using a third part package which is using the older Xamarin.Forms component Whether this may be the cause of the warning mail?

Comment: For us to know, What could be causing this issue you need to add much more details than this, for now make sure you have read this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's the Xamarin.Forms version

I saw someone faced the issue here but he consumed some third-party libraries:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/404242
It works after removing the Calabash.
Moreover, we need to change the linker behavior to make the linker remove the UIWebView part. Please refer to this blog for more information:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @LeZhu - MSFT, In that case '--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type' will work right?. Can you also help me in adding more than one mtouch arguments in VisualStudio. Currently I did it by separating by space, whether I should use comma if I have more than one mtouch arguments?

Comment: Yes,you could do it by separating by space