# WkWebView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have used WebView in one of my Xaml pages. Recently, I got a warning message from Apple regarding the Deprecation of API.

**Xamarin.Forms 4.5 or higher** – Pre-release versions of Xamarin.Forms 4.5 can be used.

**Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher** – Check your Xamarin.iOS version in Visual Studio. This version of Xamarin.iOS is included with Visual Studio for Mac 8.4.1 and Visual Studio 16.4.3.

**Remove references to UIWebView** – Your code should not have any references to UIWebView or any classes that make use of UIWebView.

I have updated my Xamarin.Forms version and Xamarin.IOS version as suggested.I am trying to understand how to  remove the references? I would like to use the WKWebView.

Do I have to explicitly define any custom renderer if I decide to continue using the WKWebView? 
How can I use it without having my app rejected ? Is WKWebView available as a tag for us to use ?

Tried to take reference from below post but I am still looking for clarity on 3rd point ---> Remove References to UIWebView.

[WebUI Deprecated mail even after the following the steps mentioned in Xamarin forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924893/webui-deprecated-mail-even-after-the-following-the-steps-mentioned-in-xamarin-fo)

Comment: So basically when it says that remove all references for UIWebview it means that do not use it anywhere, also not to use packages that use it somewhere, for instance how Lucas there pointed out Calabash, Secondly, all you need to do is add this mtouch argument `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type` and select either `Link All SDK `or at least `Link Framework and User SDK's` and you are good to go.